# Retrieving data from callback function

Tags: c++, global-variables, glfw

Were I to set a callback function in GLFW, let's say

```
glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse);
```

the most obvious way to retrieve the cursor position would be

```
vec2 m;

void mouse (GLFWwindow* window, GLdouble x, GLdouble y)
{
    m = vec2 (x, y);
}
```

However, I would prefer to do so without using a global variable. Can it be done?

Comment: What do you want `m` to be, then? Local? Member variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can associate a user pointer to a `GLFWindow`. See [`glfwSetWindowUserPointer`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651).

the pointer can be retrieved at an time form the `GLFWWindow` object by [`glfwGetWindowUserPointer`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga17807ce0f45ac3f8bb50d6dcc59a4e06)

```
struct MyWindowData
{
  GLdouble x;
  GLdouble y;
}
```

Associate a pointer to `windowData`, to the `window`:

```
MyWindowData windowData;

glfwSetWindowUserPointer( window, &windowData );
glfwSetCursorPosCallback( window, mouse );
```

Get the pointer form the `window` and Cast the pointer of type `void*` to `MyWindowData *` (Sadly you have to do the cast).

```
void mouse(GLFWwindow* window, GLdouble x, GLdouble y)
{
   MyWindowData *dataPtr = (MyWindowData*)glfwGetWindowUserPointer( window ); 
   dataPtr->x = x;
   dataPtr->y = y; 
}
```